# Discovering XML Childnodes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I need to take in XML with common parent nodes but with varying child nodes. Once I get it, I need to grab the tag names of the child nodes and use those names as headers.  In the following example, all incoming XML will be wrapped as follows:

```
<customers>
    <customer>
       ...varying child nodes that do not have child nodes themselves
    </customer>
</customers>
```

I have found that this works:

```
List<string> headerList = new List<string>();
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(someXML);

XmlNodeList xnl = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("customers/customer");

foreach (XmlNode xn in xnl)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < xn.ChildNodes.Count; x++)
    {
        headerList.Add(xn.ChildNodes[x].Name.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever looked into XmlReader or the XmlSerializer?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick;

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(someXML);
var headerList = doc.Descendants("customer").Elements().Select(x => x.Name);
```

Not necessarily "better", but it's a bit more concise I guess.

Comment: Agreed, LINQ is your friend, here!